# No application is registered as handling this file for dot files

Tags: 18.04

I use some tools to generate some dot graphs (opt -analyze -view-cfg), but I got this error:

```
gio: file:///tmp/cfg_ZNSaIiED2Ev-e32185.dot: No application is registered as handling this file
```

I think this is because I don't have applications to view dot files, then I installed graphviz from apt-get, but the error still exist, how can I fix this?

I use Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you found yet any resolution? Dotty does not display the dot cfg file correctly for me, also using LLVM...

Comment: Sadly, no, I use -dot-cfg to generate cfg manually.

Answer (score 2):

Installing `xdot` works for me.

`sudo apt install xdot`

After that you can use `opt <file> -analyze -view-cfg` as usual and the graph will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing similar issue.

If you want to generate CFG you can use **"-dot-cfg"** to produce .dot file and then you can use **dotty**  to view the dotty files

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dotty.1.html